# Unable to Authenticate Mongo-exporess on Mongo db with Docker Compose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, docker, docker-compose, mongo-express

I m trying to connect mongo express and my node app to mongo db with docker compose  but I' m unable to authenticate.
Can not connect those service with docker-compose, continusly getting this error:

Could not connect to database using connectionString: mongodb://admin:password@mongo:27017"

The following is my docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3'
services:
  app:
    build: .
    env_file: .env
    restart: always
    environment:
      - NODE_ENV=production
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    volumes:
      - .:/usr/src/app
    command: yarn dev
    depends_on:
      - mongodb
    networks:
      - mongo-compose-network
    links:
    - mongodb

  mongodb:
    container_name: mongodb
    image: mongo
    environment:
      - MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME=admin
      - MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD=password
    ports:
      - "27017:27017"
    volumes:
      - mongodbdata:/data/db
    networks:
      - mongo-compose-network


  mongo-express:
    image: mongo-express
    depends_on:
      - mongodb
    ports:
      - "8888:8081"
    links:
      - mongodb
    environment:
      - ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_ADMINUSERNAME=admin
      - ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_ADMINPASSWORD=password
      - ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_URL=mongodb://admin:password@mongo:27017
    networks:
      - mongo-compose-network

  redis:
    image: redis:latest
    ports:
      - "6379:6379"
    networks:
      - mongo-compose-network
    volumes:
      - redisdata:/data

  celery:
    build: .
    command: node celery.js worker --loglevel=info
    depends_on:
      - app
      - mongodb
      - redis
    networks:
      - mongo-compose-network
    environment:
      - CELERY_BROKER_URL=redis://redis:6379/0

volumes:
  mongodbdata:
  redisdata:

networks:
  mongo-compose-network:
    driver: bridge
```

Comment: you use @mongo instead of your service "mongod" : try mongodb://admin:password@mongod:27017

Answer (score 0):

Resolved by creating an admin user from inside the mongodb container.